# Proof that union of powersets equals powerset of union of two sets if one is subset of another

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need to prove that:

$$(A\subseteq B \vee B \subseteq A )\Leftrightarrow P(A) \cup P(B) = P(A\cup B) $$

Now I have already been able to prove that for any set A and B

$$ P(A)\cup P(B)\subseteq P(A\cup B)  $$

The next thing I tried to do then is proving:

$$(A\subseteq B \vee B \subseteq A )\Leftrightarrow P(A\cup B)\subseteq P(A)\cup P(B)  $$

But this is where I get stuck. I started with the proof from left to right, so in case 1 I assume A is a subset of B and try to prove the right side. Unfortunately, I cant come up with a prove that seems logically consistent without jumping to conclusions too quickly.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A\subseteq B$ then $A\cup B=B$ so that $\wp(A\cup B)=\wp(B)\subseteq\wp(A)\cup\wp(B)$

If $B\subseteq A$ then $A\cup B=A$ so that $\wp(A\cup B)=\wp(A)\subseteq\wp(A)\cup\wp(B)$

So in both cases we have:$$\wp(A\cup B)\subseteq\wp(A)\cup\wp(B)$$

---

Backwards: $$A\cup B\in\wp(A\cup B)\subseteq\wp(A)\cup\wp(B)$$ so that $$A\cup B\subseteq A\vee A\cup B\subseteq B$$ or equivalently $$B\subseteq A\vee A\subseteq B$$

Comment: Thank you very much! Everything is clear now... I simply overlooked the fact that If A⊆B then A∪B=B

Comment: You are welcome.